# Getting the size in bytes of an arbitrary integer

Tags: erlang, elixir

Given an integer, 98749287 say,  is there some built-in/libray function, either Erlang or Elixir, for getting the size in bytes?

To clarify, the minimum number of bytes used to represent the number in binary.

Seems simple, and have written a function using the "division by base" method and then counting bits, but after some hrs of searching docs havent found anything for what would seem useful to have.

Comment: OOC, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have to encode some integers using Basic Encoding Rules (packing arbitrary integer parts into series of 7 bits).

Comment: There is an ASN.1 module for Erlang that works rather well. Depending on your overall needs, this might be a better option (I use it regularly!).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have an unsigned integer, you can use the following snippet:

```erlang
byte_size(binary:encode_unsigned(Integer))
```

Example:

```erlang
1> byte_size(binary:encode_unsigned(3)).
1
2> byte_size(binary:encode_unsigned(256)).
2
3> byte_size(binary:encode_unsigned(98749287)).
4
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Problem with learning Elixir is that its easy to forget the Erlang documentation (or rather "avoid"). Can throw a few functions away now.

Comment: Yeah, can be tricky. This only helps if you're on OS X, but I usually use Dash and search the Erlang and Elixir documentation simultaneously for stuff like "integer", "binary" and "size" and such. That's a great way to find possibly relevant functions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this expression:

```
Value = (... your input ...),
NumBytes = size(integer_to_binary(Value, 2) + 7) div 8.
```

Reference: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#integer_to_binary-2

Comment: This is seems to work. although leaves a messy decimal that must be rounded. What was the thinking about the +7?

Comment: The +7 is to try to round up. Please change the division to a flooring or integer division, like the C operator `/`.

Comment: Make that `div 8` instead of `/ 8` for integer division.